# How do I make a Bootstrap grid column be the full height of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a sidebar using the Bootstrap Grid but I want it to stretch all the way to the bottom. [Image of what I am trying to accomplish.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDvzd.png)

I don't want to ruin the responsiveness and avoid Javascript solutions if possible.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        /* Footer CSS */
        html {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            margin-bottom: 60px;
        }
        .footer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 60px;
            background-color: #3e8f3e;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10" style="background-color: #f5e79e">
                Column that does not need to stretch
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #ffff00;">
                Sidebar/column to stretch down to the bottom (to the footer)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h5>Footer to reach down too</h5>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is also avaliable on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/tuLuazy8/3/) which will probably be a lot easier to work with.
Make sure you drag the results so that the site does not show a mobile version with columns underneath each other.

Any help is appreciated as I have been stuck on this problem for ages.

Comment: @RayKoren I didn't down vote your answer.

Comment: Is you sidebar acting as navigation menu?

Comment: @Zacy5000 I have two options: https://jsfiddle.net/grvpanchal/1k1wdu8u/ and https://jsfiddle.net/grvpanchal/g6kxjxuo/

Comment: @grvpanchal I think thats exactly what I need. Thanks, I'll try it out on my website later. Could you put that as a answer so I can vote it up?

Comment: I did something with some simple custom code, but on the v4 version of bootstrap. If Interested I can post an answer with links + my css.

Comment: Hey, have you tried adding "height:100vh" to the sidebar class? It works like a charm, let me know if that helps!

Comment: @GerardoSabetta Damn, that is so close to working. The only problem is that the footer and navigation bar cause problems with it in terms of making a unneeded scrollbar.

Comment: @GerardoSabetta Actually your suggestion helped a lot. I didn't know about vh and managed to make a solution using the calc function of CSS to stop the scroll bar from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a fairly simple solution. Thanks to everyone who responded to help though.
Credits to Gerardo Sabetta for the suggestion to use "height: 100vh".

Here is the working solution on JSFiddle: [click me.](http://jsfiddle.net/tuLuazy8/8/)

**What I did**

Using the calc function and position absolute I could make the sidebar fill up the height of the page without making a scrollbar unnecessarily and keep it responsive using @media in CSS.

**The code I added**

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .sidebar-grid {
        position: relative;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .sidebar-grid {
        height: calc(100% - 50px - 60px);
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

with "sidebar-grid" being in the class of the grid (IE. "col-md-3 sidebar-grid"). 992px is the medium desktop size for Bootstrap and is when the columns stack (when the window is less the 992px in size) due to col-md-3. If this was col-lg-3 then the 992px should be 1200px. All these sizes are from [the Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries). 50px and 60px is the size of the navbar and footer.

Please comment if you think I have done something wrong.

Comment: I'm glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

I have two option to go forward with:

1. If you like to have sidebar with grid then use `.container-table` within flex layout using [bootstrap-essentials](http://grvpanchal.github.io/bootstrap-essentials) : [jsfiddle.net/grvpanchal/1k1wdu8u](http://jsfiddle.net/grvpanchal/1k1wdu8u)
2. If you want to have a responsive sidebar `.navmenu` like use this one: [jsfiddle.net/grvpanchal/g6kxjxuo](http://jsfiddle.net/grvpanchal/g6kxjxuo)

Answer (score -1):

well...there are some things in your code that won't let side bar grow by css only...
first side-bar and nav-bar are inside a row and a container that close them in one div that close them as a box or something...so...even if you give your sidebar height:100% it won't effect anything...
seconed your footer is 100% width and also declare a specific height for it so again it won't help you to write height 100% for the side bar. I really advise you to use JS for the sidebar, there are also many examples for a complete one in bootstrap comment me if you'd like a link for an example or something

Answer (score -1):

What I did was take the sidebar out of the main row and floated it right. I also set the footer position to relative.

```css
        /* Footer CSS */
        html {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            margin-bottom: 60px;
        }
        .footer {
            position: relative;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 60px;
            background-color: #bce8f1;
        }
        body,html,.row-offcanvas {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#sidebar {
  width: inherit;
  min-width: 220px;
  max-width: 220px;
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
  float: right;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
#main {
 
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NavBar</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
 <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #ffff00;">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Sidebar</h3>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Section</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
            </div>
        <div id="main" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10" style="background-color: #f5e79e">
                Column that does not need to stretch
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h5>Footer to reach down too</h5>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: That's good but the problem is that if the user is on a phone (or a small window) the sidebar won't be responsive (IE. It won't stack under the column) which is a problem because on a phone it will all be crammed. But thanks anyway